# From which circuit, I will be able to measure high frequency signal (in MHz) by using micro controller with 200 Ksps ADC?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, frequency, conversion

I want to measure 20 MHz signal by using microcontroller with 12 bit ADC And 200 Ksps sampling rate. 
Which circuit should I design in order to measure it accurately?

Comment: What aspect of it do you want to measure?   How clean is it?   What noise or interference do you need to ignore?  What is the *analog bandwidth* of your ADC?   Likely you want some kind of down conversion protected by filtering.  Look at typical software defined radio designs.  In some cases, if the analog bandwidth is sufficient you may be able to filter the RF range to avoid aliasing and then *undersample*, folding the downconversion right into the sampling itself.  Also consider if what you want is more along the lines of a *frequency counter* than a receiver.

Comment: What aspect of it do you want to measure? => I want to measure volatge. How clean is it? => precise till uV. What is the analog bandwidth of your ADC? => I want to measure amplitude of fixed 20MHz sine wave. I want to detect the change in voltage in range of 10uV.

Comment: What voltage? Average? Momentary?

Comment: Depending on your need you may be able to build a frequency-insensitive RF power meter (basically a diode-type AM detector) and apply the ADC to the low-pass filtered output of that.

Comment: @EugeneSh.   What voltage? Average? Momentary? => I want to measure it's peak value. and changes in peak value in 10uV of range.

Comment: You mentioned a change in voltage of 10 uV. What is the nominal value of this 20 MHz sine wave? In general, when you ask a question like this, you need to provide detailed information if you expect a useful answer. You have not done this as evidenced by the numerous comments asking for more information.

Comment: Achieving 10uV sensitivity in a cheap 12-bit microcontroller ADC is unlikely to work. Sharing the same silicon chip as the microcontroller means significant digital noise injection. There is also very likely a spec limit for VRef input minimum; check the datasheet electrical characteristics table. This is the type of application that typically requires an external ADC. Since PCB layout and good thermal stability will be critical for 10uV levels, be sure to look for manufacturer published evaluation kits or reference design layouts (I design these for a living.)

Comment: @MarkU  I know 12 bit ADC is not sufficient for 10uV. I want to detect minima of adjustable band pass filter  at 10uV precision. I am thinking to use switchable gain. That will solve the problem as I can sense the lower voltages by amplifying.

Answer (score 0):

MCU clocks do not have clean performance, that is they are very jittery. Use an off chip ADC with clean sample-convert clock.